# iOS push notification with image like in iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, payload

I want to create a push notification with an image (like when you receive an iMessage with a photo).

Anyone know how it is done?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have u got any answer/way for this?Need same feature in my app

Comment: @Kalyani Nope :) This was not possible at the time. Don't think it is possible now either .

Answer (score 2):

This has changed in iOS 10! Hurrah!

https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/261-rich-notifications

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.The notification payload is up to 256 bytes long.And it is useless to use them to sent images.

Please read [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

Comment: It is increased to 2k with iOS8. I saw apps (not apple's) that does that. For example, United Airlines.

Comment: Despite the size of the payload of 2k it is not impossible to show images in notifications.

Comment: Not impossible? Did you mean not possible? Are you sure? Than how apps are doing it?

Comment: Push notification contains only logo of the app or resource that you set from bundle.

Comment: I am posting the UnitedAirlines screen shot on my question. Explain this please...

Comment: This is a Pass from Passbook, not a push notification. Notice that the image included is actually the boarding pass that would be displayed in Passbook.

Comment: You cand do that... recieve a notification. Excecute a background download transfer when push arrives and perform the Download, after its downloaded execute a LocalPushNotification with custom design..

Comment: @Mak13 nope. at the time i came to the conclusion there was no way of doing this.

Comment: Are you very sure with it? How is iMessage doing it?